# Removing existing React /Build when using postbuild script on package.json to move /Build to custom directory on `npm run build`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm working on a React app with a Flask backend and I must have React files and Flask application in a separate adjacent directories. For this setup when running npm run build I'm moving React build to a directory inside Flask application. I have setup Flask defaults to the build directory and auto moving the build on `npm run build` is working correctly except every time I need to build I must manually delete previous build.

How can I auto remove previous build before moving it to avoid error below:

```
mv: rename build to ../some/path/application/build: Directory not empty
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dod@0.1.0 postbuild: `mv build ../some/path/application/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

This is what I have added to my package.json to move my build

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "postbuild": "mv build ../some/path/application/", <-- Working OK
    ...
  },
```

Here is my attempt to auto remove the previous build:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "postbuild": "rm -rf ../some/path/application/build", <-- Not working
    "postbuild": "mv build ../some/path/application/", <-- Working OK
    ...
  },
```

Comment: you can't have two duplicate keys in json files. You can run multiple commands in one script using `&&`, try `"postbuild": "rm -rf ../some/path/application/build && mv build ../some/path/application/",`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Makes sense about the duplicate keys. I didn't think of it. Your solution actually works. Many thanks!